# Redirect inner page to homepage and open the inner page in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, mod-rewrite, redirect, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 1.3
I need to be able to redirect www.domain.com/inner.html to www.domain.com/index.html and open the inner.html page in Fancybox. How can I achieve this simply? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). you need to write a script inside `inner.html` that evaluates whether it has been opened inside fancybox or not. It will then redirect to `index.html` if opened outside fancybox .... but it also needs to tell `index.html` to open fancybox if coming from the redirection, otherwise `index.html` should open normally (not fancybox)

Inside `inner.html` you have to have at least:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
if(!parent.jQuery().fancybox) {
 alert("opened OUTSIDE of fancybox");
 // redirect to index.html and set the hash value to "inner"
 window.location = "http://domain.com/index.html#inner"
}
</script>
```

2). Now, inside `index.html` you need to evaluate if the page has been opened from the result of the redirection (the URL has the `hash` "#inner") so it will open the page `inner.html` in fancybox on page load, otherwise it will open normally (if the URL hasn't `hash` -or- has `hash` other than "#inner")

Also you have to load all your fancybox js and css files and at least this html:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://domain.com/inner.html">open inner page</a>
```

and this script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   "width": 830, // or whatever
   "height": 320,
   "type": "iframe"
  });
  // check hash
  if(window.location.hash){
   var url = window.location.hash, thisHash = new Array();
   // extract hash from URL
   thisHash  = url.split("#",2); 
   if(thisHash[1] == "inner") {
    alert("the hash is inner");
    // hash = "inner" so open "inner.html" in fancybox
    $(".fancybox").trigger("click");
   }
  }
 });//ready
</script>
```

Please bear in mind that in order to evaluate the `parent` fancybox variable (as in `inner.html`), both `inner.html` and `index.html` should belong to the same domain. Check the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more.